# Superposing Pandas time series from different years in Seaborn plot

Tags: python, date, pandas, time-series, seaborn

I have a Pandas data frame, and I want to explore the periodicity, trend, etc of the time series. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2u3MNOqrn8cYUtXblVRb21CNXc/view) is the data.

To visualize it, I want to superpose the "sub time series" for each year on the same plot (ie have the same x coordinate for data from 01/01/2000, 01/01/2001 and 01/01/2002).

Do I have to transform my date column so that each data has the same year?

Does anyone have an idea of how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Setup**
*This parses the data that you linked*

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    'data.csv', sep=';', decimal=',',
    usecols=['date', 'speed', 'height', 'width'],
    index_col=0,  parse_dates=[0]
)
```

**My Hack**
*I stripped the everything but the year from the dates and assumed the year of `2012` because it is a leap year and will accommodate Feb-29.  I splity the year into another level of a multi-index, `unstack` and `plot`*

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
        pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime('2012-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
        df.index.year
    ])

ax = df.set_index(idx).unstack().speed.plot()
lg = ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

---

*In an effort to pretty this up*

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(15, 9))

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
        pd.to_datetime(df.index.strftime('2012-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
        df.index.year
    ])

d1 = df.set_index(idx).unstack().resample('W').mean()
d1.speed.plot(ax=axes[0], title='speed')
lg = axes[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.02, 1), loc=2, ncol=1)

d1.height.plot(ax=axes[1], title='height', legend=False)
d1.width.plot(ax=axes[2], title='width', legend=False)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do it is to create a common x-axis for all years like this:

```
df['yeartime']=df.groupby(df.date.dt.year).cumcount()
```

where 'yeartime' represents the number of time measures in a year. Next, create a year column:

```
df['year'] = df.date.dt.year
```

Now, let's subset our data for the Jan 1st of years 2000, 2001, and 2002

```
subset_df = df.loc[df.date.dt.year.isin(['2000','2001',2002]) & (df.date.dt.day == 1) & (df.date.dt.month == 1)]
```

And lastly, plot it.

```
ax = sns.pointplot('yeartime','speed',hue='year',data=subset_df, markers='None')
_ =ax.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
```

[image]